# How to create a new EventEmitter and register "open" and "close" event listeners?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, ecmascript-6, eventemitter

The createEmitter function should create a new EventEmitter and register "open" and "close" event listeners. The callbacks for those events should be onOpen and onClose arguments, respectively. The opened and closed methods should raise the "open" and "close" events on the EventEmitter they will receive as emitter arguments. The callbacks should only be invoked once per emitter.

For example, after executing the following code, it should print "Opened!" and then "Closed!":

```
let emitter = createEmitter(
  () => console.log("Opened!"), () => console.log("Closed!")
);
opened(emitter);
closed(emitter);
```

My Code:

```
const events = require("events");
const myEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function createEmitter(onOpen, onClose) {    
myEmitter.on('open', onOpen); 
myEmitter.on('close', onClose);
}

function opened(emitter) {
myEmitter.emit('open', emitter); 

}
function closed(emitter) {
myEmitter.emit('close', emitter);
}

let emitter = createEmitter(
  () => console.log("Opened!"), () => console.log("Closed!")
);
opened(emitter);
closed(emitter);

module.exports.createEmitter = createEmitter;
module.exports.opened = opened;
module.exports.closed = closed;
```

Output:

```
Opened!
Closed!
```

Test Cases:

```
  OK: Example case: Correct answer 
  WRONG: createEmitter registers the correct events: Exception 
  OK: open and close functions raise the correct events: Correct answer 
  WRONG: Callbacks are only invoked once: Wrong answer
```

Could Anyone explain why the Wrong Answer and the Exception?

Comment: Your "Test Results" do not match up with the console log statements in your code, did you post the wrong results somehow? Maybe you're running the wrong script?

Comment: I have edited my question. My output is giving me the desired result, however, Test Cases are giving me 2 WRONG (a Wrong Answer and an Exception)

Comment: What are the test cases' codes?

Comment: Test cases I could not pass:
1. The opened and closed methods should raise the "open" and "close" events on the EventEmitter they will receive as emitter arguments. 
2. The callbacks should only be invoked once per emitter.
@acdcjunior

Comment: Do you have code for those test cases?

Comment: unfortunately, no!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the problem is that your `createEmitter` function doesn't create an emitter, but adds events to a pre-created one. Try it like this:

```js
const EventEmitter = require("events"); //events.EventEmitter is just a self reference

function createEmitter(onOpen, onClose) {    
  const myEmitter = new EventEmitter()
  myEmitter.on('open', onOpen); 
  myEmitter.on('close', onClose);
  return myEmitter; //This is important
}

function opened(emitter) {
  emitter.emit('open'); 
}
function closed(emitter) {
  emitter.emit('close');
}

let emitter = createEmitter(
  () => console.log("Opened!"), () => console.log("Closed!")
);
opened(emitter);
closed(emitter);

module.exports.createEmitter = createEmitter;
module.exports.opened = opened;
module.exports.closed = closed;
```

Comment: It's a better approach. The opened and closed methods should raise the "open" and "close" events on the EventEmitter they will receive as emitter arguments is CORRECT. However,  'Callbacks are not invoked once'

Comment: @nafeo What are the exact requirements?

Answer (score 7):

Replace .on() with once(). Using once() removes event listeners when the event is handled by the same function.

Answer (score 3):

One of the requirements was "The callbacks should only be invoked once per emitter".

Therefore when registering the event it should be through the function once() and not on();

```
myEmitter.once('open', onOpen); 
myEmitter.once('close', onClose);
```

Using once() the listener will listen to the event only the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your solution and the suggestions made above, find below a working code snippet that answers your queries:

```js
const EventEmitter = require("events"); //events.EventEmitter is just a self reference

function createEmitter(onOpen, onClose) {    
  const myEmitter = new EventEmitter()
  myEmitter.once('open', onOpen); 
  myEmitter.once('close', onClose);
  return myEmitter;             //This is important
}

function opened(emitter) {
  emitter.emit('open'); 
}
function closed(emitter) {
  emitter.emit('close');
}

let emitter = createEmitter(
  () => console.log("Opened!"), () => console.log("Closed!")
);
opened(emitter);
closed(emitter);

module.exports.createEmitter = createEmitter;
module.exports.opened = opened;
module.exports.closed = closed;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const EventEmitter = require("events");

function createEmitter(onOpen, onClose) {
    const myEmitter = new EventEmitter() myEmitter.once('open', onOpen);
    myEmitter.once('close', onClose);
    return myEmitter;
}

function opened(emitter) {
    emitter.emit('open');
}

function closed(emitter) {
    emitter.emit('close');
}
let emitter = createEmitter(() => console.log("Opened!"), () => console.log("Closed!"));
opened(emitter);
closed(emitter);
module.exports.createEmitter = createEmitter;
module.exports.opened = opened;
module.exports.closed = closed;
module.exports.createEmitter = createEmitter;
module.exports.opened = opened;
module.exports.closed = closed;
```

Comment: Adding explanation to your provided code will help with understanding how it solves the issue.